# How to Create Java Packages And How to Import Them In Another?

Tags: java, package

I am new in java i trying to import package from another one but the other one won't compile because it said that it can't find the first package here is what i did :

First pack code :

```
package sagar.sql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.apps.bne.exception.BneException;
import oracle.apps.bne.framework.BneWebAppsContext;
import oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneBaseSQL;

public class SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL extends BneBaseSQL {
public SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL(BneWebAppsContext paramBneWebAppsContext, 
                                String paramString) throws SQLException, 
                                                           BneException {
    Connection connection = paramBneWebAppsContext.getJDBCConnection();
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    stringBuffer.append("SELECT PARTY_NAME,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,LOCATION  WHERE org_id = 281 AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER = :1");


    if ((paramString != null) && (!paramString.trim().equals(""))) {
        stringBuffer.append("AND " + paramString);
    }

    //stringBuffer.append(" ORDER BY VENDOR_SITE_CODE, ADDRESS ");

    setQuery(connection, stringBuffer.toString());
  }
}
```

Second Pack Code:

```
package sagar.validator;


 import java.util.Hashtable;

 import oracle.apps.bne.exception.BneException;
 import oracle.apps.bne.exception.BneFatalException;
 import oracle.apps.bne.exception.BneMissingParameterException;
 import oracle.apps.bne.framework.BneWebAppsContext;
 import oracle.apps.bne.integrator.validators.BneUploadValidator;
 import oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneCompositeSQLCriteria;
 import oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneResultSet;
 import oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneSQLStatement;

 import sagar.sql.SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL;

public class SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator extends BneUploadValidator {

public String[] getDomainParameters() {
    return new String[] { "P_CUST_NUM" };
}

public BneResultSet getDomainValues(BneWebAppsContext paramBneWebAppsContext, 
                                    Hashtable paramHashtable, 
                                    BneCompositeSQLCriteria paramBneCompositeSQLCriteria) throws BneException {

    SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL sagarSupplierSiteNameSQL = null;
    BneResultSet bneResultSet = null;
    BneSQLStatement bneSQLStatement1 = new BneSQLStatement();

    if (paramBneCompositeSQLCriteria != null) {
        bneSQLStatement1 = 
                paramBneCompositeSQLCriteria.evaluate(bneSQLStatement1);
    }

    String str1 = (String)paramHashtable.get("P_CUST_NUM");

    if (str1 == null) {
        throw new BneMissingParameterException("Customer Number Field Error");
    }


    try {
        sagarSupplierSiteNameSQL = 
                new SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL(paramBneWebAppsContext, 
                                             bneSQLStatement1.getStatement());
        BneSQLStatement bneSQLStatement2 = 
            new BneSQLStatement(sagarSupplierSiteNameSQL.getQuery(), 
                                new Object[] { str1 });

        bneSQLStatement2.append("", bneSQLStatement1.getBindValues());
        bneResultSet = 
                sagarSupplierSiteNameSQL.getBneResultSet(bneSQLStatement2.getBindValuesAsArray());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new BneFatalException(exception.toString());
    }


    return bneResultSet;
}


}
```

The Terminal:

```
-bash-3.00$ javac /apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classes   
/SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL.java -d "$JAVA_TOP/sager/sql"
-bash-3.00$     
-bash-3.00$ 
-bash-3.00$ 
-bash-3.00$ 
-bash-3.00$ javac /apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classes   
/SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator.java -d "$JAVA_TOP/sager/validator"
/apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classes   
/SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator.java:15: package sagar.sql does not exist
import sagar.sql.SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL;
            ^
/apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classes   
/SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL
location: class sagar.validator.SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator
    SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL sagarSupplierSiteNameSQL = null;
    ^
/apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classes   
/SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL
location: class sagar.validator.SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator
                new SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL(paramBneWebAppsContext, 
                    ^
`3 errors
```

If you need more information about the problem i am facing please ask me and please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using cross imports, the files won't compile individually. You'll have to compile all file at once.

Also, your classes are not inside the packages it says at the top of the java files. Remove `package sagar.validator;` and `package sagar.sql;` from both files and run the following command :

```
javac /apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/*.java
```

If you want to use packages, move 
`SagarSupplierSiteNameSQL.java` inside the folder `/apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/sagar/sql` and

`SagarSupplierSiteNameValidator.java` inside `/apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/sagar/validator`.

Go inside `/apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java` and any 1 of the following 2 commands should work.

```
javac  **/*.java
```

or

```
javac  **/**/*.java
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your fast replay i will test the solution and return with feedback

Comment: My points Lower than 15 when i get to 15 point i will up vote it for sure thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It worked perfectly when i use this two commands:

```
  javac /apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classes/SagarSupplierSiteNa‌​meSQL.java -d "$JAVA_TOP"
```

And

```
 javac /apps/DEV/apps/apps_st/comn/java/classe/SagarSupplierSiteNa‌meValidator.java -d "$JAVA_TOP"
```

It created the directories of the package automatic thanks @Pankaj Singhal because your replay guided me

Comment: You should not accept your own answer which just mentions that some other guy's answer helped you. You should accept the answer which answers your question & helped you.

Comment: This is like _The Dictator_ in making.